# How to get many sums stepping through varying length lists that have specific orders?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**My Problem:**

I have a list of lists. These lists are varying length e.g. `[[2, 1, 5, 3], [2,4,8]`

For each item in each list I need to print its sum with the next list item, then the next 2 list items, until I print the sum of all of the list items. Then I move to the second list item and do the same until I have reached the last list item.

The output I need is:

**My Desired Output:**

```
2 + 1 = 3
2 + 1 + 5 = 8
2 + 1 + 5 + 3 = 11
1 + 5 = 6
1 + 5 + 3 = 9
5 + 3 = 8
2 + 4 = 6
2 + 4 + 8 = 14
4 + 8 = 12
```

**My (bad) Attempt:**

I have tried for hours but have not been able to get close. I was doing something along the lines of the below code but I am wondering if I need to make a recursive function??

```
for cluster in [[2, 1, 5, 3], [2,4,8]]:
  for trip in cluster:
    for trip_cluster_index in range(len(cluster)):
      if trip != cluster[trip_cluster_index]:
        print(cluster, trip, cluster[trip_cluster_index])
```

Comment: not sure why this was anonymously downvoted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**O(n^3)**

```
list_sum = [[2, 1, 5, 3], [2,4,8]]
list_out = []
for l in list_sum: 
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        aux = l[i-1]
        for j in range(i, len(l)):
            aux += l[j]
            list_out.append(aux)

print(list_out)
```

[3, 8, 11, 6, 9, 8, 6, 14, 12]

**O(n^2)**

```
list_sum = [[2, 1, 5, 3], [2,4,8]]
list_out = []
for l in list_sum:
    list_1 = []
    aux = l[0]
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        aux += l[i]
        list_1.append(aux)
    list_out.extend(list_1)

    sum_list = 0
    for j in range(0, len(list_1)-1):
        sum_list += l[j]
        list_2 = [x-sum_list for x in list_1[j+1:]]
        list_out.extend(list_2)

print(list_out)
```

[3, 8, 11, 6, 9, 8, 6, 14, 12]

**Inverted O(n^3)**

```
list_sum = [[2, 1, 5, 3], [2,4,8]]
list_out = []
for l in list_sum:   
    for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
        aux = sum(l[i:])
        list_out.append(aux)
        for j in range(len(l)-1,i+1,-1):
            aux -= l[j]
            list_out.append(aux)

print(list_out)
```

[11, 8, 3, 9, 6, 8, 14, 6, 12]

Comment: Thanks I will use this one. Just what I needed

Comment: The first solution is simpler but slower for very large lists.

Comment: Hey Manuel, what if I wanted to count down? i.e. outputting [11, 8, 3, 9, 6, 8, 14, 6, 12]. Thanks so much.

Comment: Add count down to solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want.

```
n = -1
listy =  [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
for l in listy:
    while n < len(listy)-1:

        n +=1
        total = sum(l) + sum(listy[n])
        print(total)
```

Comment: You could also store those results in a list with .append

Comment: Hey Jeff, what if I wanted to count down? i.e. outputting [11, 8, 3, 9, 6, 8, 14, 6, 12]. Thanks so much.

Comment: you can start with listy[-1] which is [3,3,3] and count downwards with n. You'll need to multiply the length of the string by -1 to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that your output must contain the whole equations, and this is what I came up with:

```
L=[[2, 1, 5, 3], [2,4,8]]
for i in L:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        for k in range(j+2, len(i)+1):
            print(' + '.join([str(n) for n in i[j:k]]), '=', sum(i[j:k]))
```

Hope it is what you were looking for!

Comment: Hey Michele, what if I wanted to count down? i.e. outputting [11, 8, 3, 9, 6, 8, 14, 6, 12]. Thanks so much.